# How can i hide the status bar in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, statusbar

I have a simple question, how can I hide a link in the status bar in my browser.

I've tried with this:

```
<a href="http://www.sell.com/?referrer=225"
   onMouseOver="window.status='http://www.sell.com';
               return true" onMouseOut="window.status=''">Click here</a>
```

(Taken from a tutorial)
But it doesn't work, if somebody would help me, I would be very happy! ;-)

Comment: You can do id if you allow it in your browser. Which browser do you have?

Comment: @EirNym chrome. How can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

You can't (at least in current browsers), which is a good thing.  It would help phishing attacks a great deal to disguise the link.

Comment: Yes you can do this using javascript. See this example: http://jsbin.com/obira4/4/edit

Comment: @Georg - This isn't really doing that, Ctrl+Click, Shift+Click, etc don't work...this *emulates* the clicking, but it isn't the same.  For example a middle click still opens the `href`, not your `onclick` (though this varies by browser, I'm using Chrome).

Comment: @Nick: You're right. But for his application that should suffice.

Comment: @Georg - Due respect, I think that's a bit presumptuous, you know nothing about his application, we've just seen markup for an anchor :)   The only thing we do know is that it's for referrals, and with your approach it would lose the referrer for all those click types it doesn't handle :)

Comment: @Nick: In other comments he tells us that he needs it for a affiliate network. Therefore I thought he just wants to remove the *referrer=123* part.

Comment: @Georg - He needs that part, he just don't want to show it in the status bar :)

Comment: @Nick: Exactly, that's why I would include the referrer link in the javascript code. I don't think it matters if a low amount of clicks don't have the *referrer* part.

Comment: @Georg - I think you drastically underestimate how much the referrer part matters, we're typically talking about rewards for your clicks here, sometimes money..it certainly does matter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking to do this in order to hide affiliation links, there may be a better way.

It makes far more sense to loop through all your links, say, under a broad `$("a.out")` selector, then get and store their real href into element storage, replace it with a dummy one (and the title attribute if you have to).

You then attach a click event handler that stops the default event, reads back the original href and sets it as the location.href, effectively disguising the links to all that have js enabled.

Eg code in mootools:

```
(function() {
    var links = document.getElements("a.out");

    links.each(function(el) {
        // save original
        el.store("href", el.get("href"));
        // replace it.
        el.set("href", el.get("data-link"));

        el.addEvents({
            click: function(e) {
                e.stop();
                // console.log(e);

                document.location.href = this.retrieve("href");
            },
            contextmenu: function(e) {
                e.stop();
                // do something on right click so we dont get caught
                alert("hi");
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Which works fine on this markup:

```
<a href="http://www.energyhelpline.com/energy/rg_home.aspx?aid=107" rel="nofollow" class="out" title="Enegry savings" data-link="http://www.energyhelpline.com/">Swap Energy Provider</a><br />

<a href="http://www.moneysupermarket.com/link.asp?Source=MSE&Section=utils" rel="nofollow" class="out" title="Money supermarket" data-link="http://www.moneysupermarket.com/">Money Supermarket</a>
```

With data-link containing what we SHOW to end users instead.

Comment: This encounters the same drawback as [Georg's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315029/how-can-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-the-browser/4315283#4315283): doesn't work as expected when using Ctrl+click, Shift+click, middle-click...

Comment: this is the weirdest thing i've ever seen suggested :D

Comment: hehe. and yet here it is, working: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/r7QLb/ (test via mootools). incidentally @marcel: shift/ctrl clicks are handled fine. only middle click is not. right click can also be handled via a `contextmenu` event.

Comment: No, shift/ctrl clicks don't work as intended: you simply override those, always opening the new location in the current window/tab, not a new one.

Comment: you can inspect the event object and query the state of the shift and control keys and act accordingly.

Comment: But you can't reliably open a new window or tab, e.g., using `window.open`: it's up to the browser how those are handled, e.g., I said my browser it should always open a new window in a new tab. With shift+click I always open a new window, regardless of this setting. It would be very annoying when I issue a shift+click and due to this JS behaviour a new tab is opened instead.

Comment: fair enough but are you getting sidetracked here? the objective really was to hide the affiliation link from the 99th percentile user who does not know what a shift or control click do, not how to invent a cross-browser behavioural replacement for hrefs. there's yet another thing you can do anyway: when clicked, change the href back to the original and then allow the click event to bubble / continue. http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/r7QLb/3/

Comment: Correct, I understand the OP's inital goal, but I'm not so sure the number of users that know about ctrl/shift+click is that low. That said, nice you provided a solution that at least works using ctrl/shift+click.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that will hide your original link tread text in a browsers status bar area

Please note: not sure which browsers it works on but works fine in IE9

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';return false;">If You Put Your Mouse Over This Text You Won't See Link In Status Bar Area</a>
```

When you run your mouse over the link, all you see in the status bar is `javascript:void(0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text of the status bar using javascript with `window.status` attribute. E.g. http://www.htmlite.com/JS017.php

If you REALLY need, to disable the status bar in a browser, you can get a copy of an open-source browser code base, remove all code for the status bar and redistribute it to your users, but I doubt this is what you mean/need.

Why do you need to hide the link in the status bar? A security issue with not wanting to expose the URL could be dealt with in another way.

Comment: It's because i am making an affiliate company and i need to delete the link in the status bar, like all the other affiliate networks have, maybe they are using another method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using javascript for your link:

Here's [how](http://jsbin.com/obira4/4/edit):

```
function goToBing() {
  window.location.href = "http://bing.com";
}
```

and

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="goToBing();return false;">Link to Google</a>
```

As Nick Craver said, this doesn't work in all circumstances (control-click, middle-click etc.) but should work for you, because you don't *relay* on the javascript link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with javascript + jQuery that works with ctrl click, shift click, middle click, etc. It does break right click, but if the goal is to hide the link I guess that's not a big deal.

I take no responsability whatsoever what you do with this though, I did this mostly for fun, but it does look pretty evil.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').each(function() {
       var address = $(this).attr('href');
       var element = $(this).contents().unwrap().wrap('<div/>').parent();
       element.data("hrefAddress", address).addClass("link");

       element.click(function() {               
           var newWindow = window.open(element.data("hrefAddress"), '_blank');
           newWindow.focus();
       });
   });
});​
```

CSS:

```
.link {
    color: #00f;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.link:hover {
    color: #00a;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
    <a href="http://www.bing.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
</div>​
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KYLx/1/)**