# How to remove the FULL link from your bottom

Tags: html, css, browser, hyperlink

When you go over a link you'll see a white box with the full link on your left bottom of the browser.
How do you remove this from my website?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

That box is inserted by your browser, not the page. You [can't remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315029/how-can-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-the-browser), and for good reason -- it's there to help you understand where a link will take you, and anyone wanting to hide that information is up to something dubious.

Comment: Itsn't meant for something suspectious. I want to finish my script by removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use inline JavaScript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href ='http://www.google.com';">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the browser doing that. You can't remove it. It's a good thing too, so the user can see where they're going.

With that said, you can javascript the location to a new page (of course you can style this like a link, if you want).

```
<span onclick="location.href = 'url';">Click Me!</span>
```

If you just did this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href ='url';">click me!</a>
```

, you'd still get a white box (saying `thispage/#`) at the bottom because it's still a link. So, if you want to remove that box all together, use the first option.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxLcJ/) (Note: This particular example won't work in JSFiddle, but you can still implement it into your own page)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove like using script like:

```
$("a").attr("href", "#")
```

or with conditional statement

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', '#')
```